# MS Access data into Azure Blob

Tags: python, ms-access, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

Data is in MS Access and it's in one of the shared drive on the network. I need this data in azure blob storage as CSV files. Can anyone please suggest me how can this be possible?

Comment: shared drive is MS OneDrive?

Answer (score 1):

You can move data to Azure Blob storage in several ways, You could use either Azcopy: located here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10 , Or Storage Explorer(GUI): https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/

OR using Python SDK:

```html
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(container, file, file)
```

Python SDK can be found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python

When it comes to changing the format from Access to CSV, it's something not related to Azure Storage, you can try existing libraries for that conversion, then upload to blob storage.